# how to open paypal login in same window on click of button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to open paypal login in same window, on click of paypal button, here i have added my script can anyone please check my script and help me to resolve this issue ? currently it is opening in separate window, any help will be really appreciated.

```
<div id="paypal-button-container" target="_self"></div>
  <script>
   paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '4'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // Authorize the transaction
      actions.order.authorize().then(function(authorization) {
        // Get the authorization id
        var authorizationID = authorization.purchase_units[0]
        .payments.authorizations[0].id
        return fetch('http://localhost/Checkout-PHP-SDK-develop/test.php', {     
          method: 'post',    
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID,
            authorizationID: authorizationID
          })
        });
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 1):

The JS SDK PayPal button will always keep its opening website in the background and open a small in-context popup window to approve the payment. This behavior is as designed. There is no way to make the JS SDK button behave differently, and there is no reason you should want it to behave differently.

Doing a full page redirect away from your site is an old integration method, for old websites. The JS SDK was created and exists specifically to ***avoid*** such a redirect.

---

As a separate issue, it appears you are mixing calls to `actions.order.create(` / `actions.order.authorize(` with a later fetch to something using the `Checkout-PHP-SDK`.  This does not make any sense.

If you are going to use a server-side integration, do not use the actions.order functions for anything.

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (or in your case 'Authorize Order'), [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture (or in your case, authorize) API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures/authorizations[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server